# Chef Error "RuntimeError: Please save server before accessing metadata"

Tags: chef, rackspace

I'm trying to create a new server on the Rackspace Cloud using Chef and I keep coming across this error in Chef:

> RuntimeError: Please save server before accessing metadata

Any ideas?

Comment: Please use the title as a description of your post. I copied the error in to the body of your post for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error message is coming from an update to the fog project. [This commit](https://github.com/fog/fog/commit/4116970d662f90fa06fe8f6f0245998073bc2886) introduces the error message that you're seeing. I'm able to duplicate the error as well with fog 1.9.0 which was released 4 days ago.

Use these commands to roll back to fog v1.8.0:

```
$ gem uninstall fog
$ gem install --version 1.8.0 fog
```

That fixed the issue for me! The fog developers are [working on a pull request](https://github.com/fog/fog/pull/1495) and it sounds like they'll have a new release soon (perhaps called v1.9.1).

Comment: I can confirm that using the just released fog 1.10 also fixes the issue!